# Getting point coordinates by clicking a dygraph within RStudio viewer pane

Tags: r, rstudio, dygraphs

Here's a simple dygraph:

```
library(dygraphs)  
dg <- dygraph(ldeaths)  
dg
```

As your mouse moves over the series, individual values are displayed. I'd like to click on a point and have the x coordinate (i.e., the date) displayed on the console or saved to a variable. How can I accomplish that? Looks like the answer has to do with dyCallbacks(), but I can't really figure it out. e.g.,

```
> d <- dg %>% dyCallbacks(pointClickCallback = 'function(e, p) {return
> p.x;}')   d$x$attrs$pointClickCallback   [1] "function(e, p) {return
> p.x;}"   attr(,"class")   [1] "JS_EVAL"
```

Thanks in advance,
Fabio

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Javascript, but if you are open to shiny, you can get what you want. Using the *click input binding* from `Shiny` you can print the x variable and with Shiny you can also easily save it if you want. Here is a minimum example of what you can do:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    dygraphOutput("dygraph"),
    br(),
    textOutput("clicked", inline = TRUE)
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {


  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(ldeaths) 
  })

  output$clicked <- renderText({
    strftime(req(input$dygraph_click$x), "%d %b %Y")
  })

  clickedPr <- reactive({
    print(strftime(req(input$dygraph_click$x), "%d %b %Y"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$dygraph_click$x,{

      write.csv(clickedPr(), "test.csv") 
    })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Just for extra emphasis. "input$dygraph_click$x" means that the dygraphOutput element in the UI has an id of dygraph as in this example. Therefore, if on your UI, your dygraphOutput id is something else, replace the "dygraph" in  "input$dygraph_click$x" with the id name.

Comment: Do you know why this don't working when the Shiny App is deployed at shinyapps.io? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60281465/9300556

Comment: It will be better to change the input variable in `input$dygraph_click$x` to something other than `dygraph` . People may misunderstand it to be a reserved word.